# The trajectory of a falling rope from a frictionless surface to the ground

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

There's a mechanics question that has been bothering me for a long time: A rope with length L and mass m slides off a frictionless table (with gravity as the sole acting force). How will the shape/movement of the rope changes as it is thrown off the table?

I have figured out that the first step to solving this question is to find out what the Normal Contact Force and Tension is at the instance when the rope is thrown off the table (which is when l=L/2), as this will allow me to gain a better idea of the forces acting on the rope at the instance the rope is thrown off the table.

Here's what I've worked out so far:
[image]

Given how the Normal Contact Force acts upwards, and that gravity acts on the rope thereafter, I am wondering how I may proceed to further calculate the movement of the rope once it is swing out of the table. Any forms of help/hints/primary workings would be extremely helpful for me!

Comment: This site's [homework policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) holds regardless of where the question came from. This question is off-topic because it does not ask about a specific physics concept or show any effort to work through the problem.